# FIRAuth Notification Manager Thread 1: "-[NSTaggedPointerString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa03793f4879b0f44"

Tags: flutter, xcode, firebase-authentication

Im develop with flutter using firebase auth package.
But im stuck on this exception.
After the install. The app crash when i call the auth function and show this message on Xcode:

```
Thread 1: "-[NSTaggedPointerString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa03793f4879b0f44"
```

This is my code for Phone Auth

```
dynamic codigoVerificacao;

  _verificarTel(dynamic tel) async {
    await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: tel,
        verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
          try {
            await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential).then((value) async {
              if (value.user != null) {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/');
              }
            });
          } catch (e) {
            print('Código invalido');
          }

          print('Verification Completed');
        },
        verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException exception) {
          print(exception.message);
        },
        codeSent: (verificationId, forceResendingToken) {
          setState(() {
            //codigoVerificacao = verificationId;
          });
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: ((verificationId) {
          setState(() {
            //codigoVerificacao = verificationId;
          });
        }),
        timeout: const Duration(seconds: 60));
  }
```

Im using a real ios 16.6 device

Thank you for your attention